# Using R to find sequential replicates in columns/fields in data frame

Tags: r, database, text-processing, data-cleaning

There is a data table named `dt` (below) which has 5 columns. The nature of the data is in a way that the `REG` is always *consistent and unique*  BUT the `ID` for the same `REG` may be different (*i.g.* `REG` 8888).

```
dt:
        ID    Var1  Var2 REG    Var3
    1   000AA   bs  km  8888    wz
    2   000kk   sd  zx  5555    ec
    3   111XX   ty  cn  2222    re
    4   000PP   dg  ed  6666    df
    5   000AA   sd  qq  8888    gh
    6   000DD   df  we  9999    cb
    7   000AA   ht  iy  8888    nb
    8   800BB   as  et  8888    mo
    9   111XX   ty  rt  2222    qe
    10  000AA   gd  uu  8888    xc
```

**Intention:** 
Find the replicates in `REG` as a row (full information with all columns) which have different `ID`.As an example, there are two replicates in `REG` : 8888 & 2222 BUT 8888 is the one important because only `REG` 8888 had two different `ID` : 000AA & 800BB.

**The expected outcome:**

```
ID  Var#1   Var#2   REG Var#3
000AA   bs  km  8888    wz
000AA   sd  qq  8888    gh
000AA   ht  iy  8888    nb
800BB   as  et  8888    mo
000AA   gd  uu  8888    xc
```

I know how to identify the duplicate in `REG` but do not know how to discriminate those which have different `ID` in `R`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dt)`), grouped by 'REG', `if` the `length` of the `unique` elements are greater than 1, then Subset the Data.table (`.SD`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, if(uniqueN(ID)>1) .SD , REG][, names(dt), with = FALSE]
#      ID Var1 Var2  REG Var3
#1: 000AA   bs   km 8888   wz
#2: 000AA   sd   qq 8888   gh
#3: 000AA   ht   iy 8888   nb
#4: 800BB   as   et 8888   mo
#5: 000AA   gd   uu 8888   xc
```

---

A similar option in `dplyr` is

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
   group_by(REG) %>%
   filter(n_distinct(ID)>1)
#     ID  Var1  Var2   REG  Var3
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <chr>
#1 000AA    bs    km  8888    wz
#2 000AA    sd    qq  8888    gh
#3 000AA    ht    iy  8888    nb
#4 800BB    as    et  8888    mo
#5 000AA    gd    uu  8888    xc
```

---

Or a `base R` option with `ave`

```
dt[with(dt, ave(ID, REG, FUN =function(x) length(unique(x)))>1),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a second base R alternative using `table`, `colSums`, and subsetting.

```
# get the count of unique IDs for each REG
IDCount <- colSums(with(df, table(ID, REG)) > 0)

# subset to include only REGs with more than one ID
df[df$REG %in% names(IDCount)[IDCount > 1],]
      ID Var1 Var2  REG Var3
1  000AA   bs   km 8888   wz
5  000AA   sd   qq 8888   gh
7  000AA   ht   iy 8888   nb
8  800BB   as   et 8888   mo
10 000AA   gd   uu 8888   xc
```